# How to set interval between two keyboard events?

Tags: python, time, pygame

I want to make the player move in maze each block at a time.

I tried using a clock and `time.time()` but those didn't work.

This is my game loop:

```
while self.running:
    self.counter += 1
    self.clock.tick(self.fps)

    if self.counter == self.fps:
        self.counter = 0
        self.canUpdate = True
```

This is the code for movement:

```
if self.game.canUpdate:
    if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
        self.moveDown()
        self.game.canUpdate = False

def moveDown(self):
    if self.canMoveTo(self.gridx, self.gridy+1):
        for sprite in self.game.sprites:
            if sprite != self:
                sprite.y -= self.game.gridSize
                self.gridy += 1
                print(self.gridy, self.game.canUpdate)
```

Upon one press of the down arrow `gridy` increment to over 500 and `self.game.canUpdate` remains True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `time.sleep()`

```
import time    
time.sleep(500)
```

call this block with your key event, so for next key pressing, your code execution stops for 500s and then it waits for next key-press event. And moreover `Counter()` needs to count for 500 which needs more CPU than `sleep()` if you are planning something bigger.

Comment: @danielchen, I am glad that you found what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [event loop](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) or [`pygame.event.wait`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.wait) if you want to move once per keypress. When you press the down key, a single `pygame.KEYDOWN` event with the `key` attribute `pygame.K_DOWN` will be added to the event queue. Just check if this key was pressed in the event loop and then move the sprites.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')

pos = pg.Vector2(120, 80)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                # This will be executed once per event.
                pos.y += 20
            elif event.key == pg.K_UP:
                pos.y -= 20

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 128, 255), (pos, (20, 20)))
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```